# how to set a value by default inside a mat select in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material-table, mat-select

I have a screen with Angular, it is a table that shows data from DB through a rest api in Java, the **esValido** field only brings values ​​1 and 0 as shown in the first image.

[image]

What I want to do is place a mat-select in the **esValido** field, and show the values ​​Yes and No, where Yes is 1, and No is 0

The mat select component already shows the values ​​**Yes** and **No** when displayed, but what I want is that by default when you enter the screen the Mat-select shows the value it brings from the DB, as shown in the first image, but already with the value Yes and No, but it doesn't show the value

[image]

I am using the [value] property, but it does not take it, what am I missing to show the default value?

HTML

```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="esValido">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ES VALIDO </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
    <mat-select [value]="element.esValido">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let valid of esValidoArr" [value]="valid.valor">
    {{ valid.label}}
    </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    </td>
    </ng-container>
```

component.ts

```
esValidoArr = [
    { label: 'Yes', valor: 1 },
    { label: 'No', valor: 0 },
  ];

//get the list from service
  dataSource: any;
  private obtenerLista() {
    this.controlService.obtenerLista().subscribe((response) => {
      this.control = response.data;
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.control);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    });
  }
```

or how else can i do it?

How could it be done with the [selected] property?

I hope you can help me

Answer (score 0):

You can bind that with the `ngModel` like that:

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="element.esValido">

    <mat-option *ngFor="let valid of esValidoArr" [value]="valid.valor">
    {{ valid.label}}
    </mat-option>

</mat-select>
```

Comment: I tried like that but it doesn't take it,  any other way?

Comment: I already saw what was my mistake, in the service the value of the field is as a string "1" y "0" and in my array I was placing it as numeric, that's why it didn't take it, but I already changed it and it works

Comment: @Root93 happy to hear :)